# Uploading a module(.zip file:)- Guidance_Simplepage-master.zip

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add this module named Guidance_Simplepage.  How do I add Guidance_Simplepage-master.zip(downloaded from GitHub Repository) into my Magento.  Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unzip this file in your local machine open file-zilla go to magento root and merge the files and your work is done.

Hope this answer help you.

Comment: There are  4 files and a folder"app"namely:  composer.json, license.txt, modman, Readme.md.  Now, should I copy all these files as well as our app folder into this path: /public_html/my_site/

Comment: Yes merge  all files in your magento root